# Consumer does not know partition revoke

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Topic Name : testTopic
Total # of message at topic : 1
Partition : 8
Consumer group Name : Consumer1
Consumer language : Java with partition listener impl
Infrastructure : having 4 jvms running parallel (which means, 4 consumers are running with same group name)

problem : when i start my first consumer Lister call back methods are called and partition assignments are done.. this consumer started processing my messages.

take an example, this consumer is holding a message MSG-1 and my processor is processing the message(I intentionally put 20 mille second as thread wait). so, did not committed MSG-1 back to topic with offset.

properties of the consumer 
session.timeout.ms = 15 mille seconds.

In the mean time, consumer 2 started,

this consumer started, assigned partition(properly call back methods are called) and did not consumed the messages because, these 2 messages are hold by consumer 1 .

now, from consumer heart beat interval exceed and broker considered that consumer-1 is dead and reassigned the partition at consumer-2(all) 
now call back method called at consumer-2 (assigned & revoked). In the mean time, my session timeout is expired and msg-1 and msg-2 put back to topic and picked up consumer 2.

now, i have processed msg-1 && msg-2 two times.... one time from consumer-1 and consumer-2

My problem here is,

1. Consumer-1 did not get called with partition revoked call back method ?
2. after my Thread sleep completes (from consumer -1 ) he is trying to commit the offset with partition.... we are getting partition re-assignment is done .. u cant commit. this is correct, but how can i get the call back method form consumer-1....

-Naresh.

Answer (score 0):

> Consumer-1 did not get called with partition revoked call back method ?

The consumer can only get a partition revoked call back, if it participates in a rebalance. However, because it timed out and did drop out of the group, it does not participate in a rebalance and the broker does not send a any information to the consumer. Therefore, the consumer does not know that the partitions is revoked (and hence, no call back).

> after my Thread sleep completes (from consumer -1 ) he is trying to commit the offset with partition.... we are getting partition re-assignment is done .. u cant commit. this is correct

Not sure what you mean by `we are getting partition re-assignment is done`: because the consumer does not participate in the rebalance, it still *thinks* it owns the partitions. Hence, it tries to commit, and as you correctly said, it is (correctly) not allowed to commit as it dropped out of the group.

> but how can i get the call back method form consumer-1....

You need to re-join the group by calling `poll()` again to get back into healthy state.

**General comment:** Your timeout configurations seems rather low and it's not recommended to have such small timeouts in practice. I think it will be hard to get a stable group with such low timeouts, as most likely consumers will hit the timeout regularly, dropping out of the group, and need to rejoin again.